# Veutify Slide Group Cutting Off on Window Reize

Tags: css, vue.js, layout, menu, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify's v-slide-group within a v-app-bar and am passing show-arrows prop to the slide group.

This allows when the window is sized down and the menu is cut off to have arrows instead of a scroll bar in the app bar.

The problem is when the arrows are use to paginate the menu to at least the second page and then the window is increased in size enough that it would fit all the items and eliminate the pagination, the items that were not previously on screen disappear and the toolbar is cut off.

It seems to happen when the screen width increases past the menu width in the decreased window size.

The arrow will disappear and the items will get cut off when the window is increased pas that size. If the window is decreased again the arrow reappear and the menu items can be navigated back to the previous pages.

Has anyone encountered this? It almost certainly has to do with the layout parameters of the slide group. However layout is my weak point.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4m2j.png)

Comment: any solution for this?